# css and php doesnt work

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles

For some reason it doesnt work.
The css stores at style.css but also the style inside the checkbox line doesnt effect.

my website is: http://tinyurl.com/8g8ev2m

Thanks...

p.s I work with wordpress and "PHP Code for posts" plugin, though Im not sure its matter

```
.Checkboxstyle {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
    height: 150px!important;
    font-size: 150%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px; 
    background-image: url(http://doarna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/XCellcom.gif);}
}


<?php

global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_organization where type='תקשורת'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $MEATZBEN = $result->NAME;
        $MEATZBENID = $result->ID;
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$MEATZBENID'  class='Checkboxstyle' 
               style='font-size: 100px;' value='$MEATZBEN'>. $MEATZBEN<br />";

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your markup was actually correct, the problem here is you are applying a color to a checkbox - an element that displays no text. You need the color class to be applied to whatever text you have next to the checkbox.

```
<style>
.Checkboxstyle { color: red;}
</style>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1"> <label class="Checkboxstyle">This is my checkbox</label>
```

Comment: when I try color:red it did work, but when when I try other properties as height: 150px it doesnt, any suggestion? thanks

Comment: label is not a block level element. You need to add display:block to modify positioning and dimensions

Comment: I addes my all properties. Thanks